# Must declare the scalar variable "@Name"

Tags: asp.net

I have these includes:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
```

My connection string is

```
public partial class Directory : System.Web.UI.Page      
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=10.4.33.61;Initial Catalog=Bank_Reconciliation;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=****;Password=****");
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
```

My method to search by string and display in data grid view (naming search button as `btnsearch`) is

```
protected void btnsearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string str = "select * from Employee where (Name like '%' + @search +       '%') ";
    SqlCommand xp = new SqlCommand(str, con);
    xp.Parameters.Add("@search", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtsearch.Text;

    con.Open();
    xp.ExecuteNonQuery();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
    da.SelectCommand = xp;
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds,"Name");
    GridView1.DataSource = ds;
    GridView1.DataBind();
    con.Close();
  }
}
```

I receive the following error:

> Must declare the scalar variable "@Name".

Why is this, and how do I fix it?

Comment: Where does the '@name' come in? There's no '@name' in your code. Are you showing us the right code?

Comment: yes its the right code!

Comment: Where is the @Name in the code? Can you paste the bit of your program that uses @Name?

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to have the TSQL just use LIKE @search, and handle it when adding the parameter:

```
protected void btnsearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string str = @"SELECT * FROM Employee WHERE Name LIKE @search";
    SqlCommand xp = new SqlCommand(str, con);
    xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@search", "%" + txtSearch.Text + "%");

    con.Open();
    xp.ExecuteNonQuery();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
    da.SelectCommand = xp;
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds,"Name");
    GridView1.DataSource = ds;
    GridView1.DataBind();
    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure where do you get the variable @Name. Can you please specify on what line does the error came in?

Answer (score 0):

Change you button click code to this:

```
protected void btnsearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string str = "select * from Employee where (Name like '%" + @search +       "%') ";
    SqlCommand xp = new SqlCommand(str, con);
    xp.Parameters.Add("@search", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtsearch.Text;

    con.Open();
    xp.ExecuteNonQuery();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
    da.SelectCommand = xp;
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(ds, dt);
    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    GridView1.DataBind();
    con.Close();
  }
}
```

It puts proper quotes for like operator, and also used DataTable instead of DataSet. You can also use DataSet but here it seems no need for that.